# Pandas grouping by column one and adding comma separated entries from column two

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas data frame with approximately 5 million rows with 2 columns "top_level_domain" and "category".  I would like to like to create a new dataframe with distinct top_level_domain 's and a category column that is comma separated for the unique categories.  This dataframe already has categories that are comma separated by nature.  Other domains like google will have repeating category, but I only want one.

Dataframe:

```
df1
    top_level_domain      category
1   google.com            Search Engines
2   service-now.com       Business, Software/Hardware
3   google-analytics.com  Internet Services
4   live.com              None Assigned
5   google.com            Content Server
6   google.com            Search Engines
7   inspectlet.com        Internet Services
8   doubleclick.net       Online Shopping, Web Ads
9   google.com            Search Engines
10  doubleclick.net       Ads
```

Desired output:

```
df2
    top_level_domain      category
1   google.com            Search Engines, Content Server
2   service-now.com       Business, Software/Hardware
3   google-analytics.com  Internet Services
4   live.com              None Assigned
7   inspectlet.com        Internet Services
8   doubleclick.net       Online Shopping, Web Ads, Ads
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

I have tried all of the examples from [Pandas groupby multiple columns, list of multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584363/pandas-groupby-multiple-columns-list-of-multiple-columns)

And others like the one below but I am still getting duplicates in the category column.

```
distinct_category = distinct_category.groupby('top_level_domain')['category'].agg(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x))).reset_index()
```

But I am getting duplicates in the columns

```
1   zoho.com    Online Shopping, Interactive Web Applications, Interactive Web Applications, Interactive Web Applications, Motor Vehicles
1   zohopublic.com  Internet Services, Motor Vehicles, Internet Services, Online Shopping, Internet Services
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First split column by comma, then `groupby` by column and use generator for flatten nested lists with `set` and `join`:

```
df = (distinct_category['category'].str.split(', ')
                    .groupby(distinct_category['top_level_domain'])
                    .agg(lambda x: ', '.join(set(y for z in x for y in z)))
                    .reset_index())
print (df)

       top_level_domain                        category
0       doubleclick.net   Ads, Online Shopping, Web Ads
1  google-analytics.com               Internet Services
2            google.com  Content Server, Search Engines
3        inspectlet.com               Internet Services
4              live.com                   None Assigned
5       service-now.com     Business, Software/Hardware
```

Another solution is assign back splitted values:

```
df = (distinct_category.assign(category = distinct_category['category'].str.split(', '))
                       .groupby('top_level_domain')['category']
                       .agg(lambda x: ', '.join(set(y for z in x for y in z)))
                       .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 2):

First expand your dataframe, so each row contains one category only:

```
split = df['category'].str.split(', ')
lens = split.str.len()

df = pd.DataFrame({'top_level_domain': np.repeat(df['top_level_domain'].values, lens),
                   'category': np.concatenate(split)})
```

Then remove duplicates and use `agg` with `str.join`:

```
res = df.drop_duplicates()\
        .groupby('top_level_domain')['category'].agg(','.join)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
df =df.groupby('top_level_domain')['category'].agg([('category', ', '.join)]).reset_index()
```